# Mathematica clears all definitions or crashes with the following code, can anyone reproduce the bug?

Tags: crash, debugging

I am working on a simple code, however Mathematica crashes or clears all definitions each time I will try to do anything with matrix `B`. Even when I just print it out. The code producing the problem is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Cs = With[{aT = {0., 98., 201., 316., 428., 571.}, 
    Cp = {917., 978., 1028., 1078., 1133., 1230.}}, 
   Interpolation[Transpose@{aT, Cp}]];

Capp[T_] := 
 With[{T1 = 582., T2 = 652., Tm = 617., A = 11371.42}, 
  A Cos[\[Pi] (T - Tm)/(T2 - T1)]^2]

Cn[T_] := 
 With[{C1 = 1180., T1 = 582., T2 = 652., Tm = 617.}, 
  Cs[T] + 0.5 (C1 - Cs[T]) (1. + Tanh[8. (T - Tm)/(T2 - T1)])]
Ct[T_] := 
 With[{T1 = 582., T2 = 652.}, 
    Piecewise[{{Cn[#], # <= T1}, {Cn[#] + 
        Capp[#], # >= T1 && # <= T2}, {Cn[#], True}}]] & /@ T

\[Rho] = With[{T = {0., 98., 201., 316., 428., 571., 600., 610., 
      720.}, \[Rho] = {2705., 2685., 2670., 2640., 2620., 2575., 
      2550., 2375., 2300.}}, 
   Interpolation[Transpose@{T, \[Rho]}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]];

k = With[{T = {0., 98., 201., 316., 428., 571., 600., 700., 800.}, 
    k = {162., 177., 192., 207., 223., 253., 210., 90., 100.}}, 
   Interpolation[Transpose@{T, k}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]];

ra[T_] := 1./(\[Rho][T] Ct[T])


L = 2.; (*domain length*)
Ts = 50.; (*simulation time*)
Tm = 700.; (*max temperature*)
a = 3.;
T[t_, x_] := 0.5 (Tm Exp[-a x] Cos[t - a x] + Tm)
Plot[Evaluate@Table[T[t, x], {t, 0, Ts, Ts/10}], {x, 0, L}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
(*
Plot[T[t,0],{t,0,Ts},PlotRange\[Rule]All,AxesOrigin\[Rule]{0,0}]
Plot[T[t,L],{t,0,Ts},PlotRange\[Rule]All,AxesOrigin\[Rule]{0,0}]
*)
Plot[{T[t, 0], T[t, L]}, {t, 0, Ts}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Plot[T[0, x], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

kxx[x_] := k[x]

\[Phi][t_, x_] = 
  Simplify[D[T[t, x], t] - 
    ra[T[t, x]] D[kxx[T[t, x]] D[T[t, x], x], x]];
eq = D[u[t, x], t] - 
    ra[u[t, x]] D[kxx[u[t, x]] D[u[t, x], x], x] == \[Phi][t, x];

maxIter = 50;

Nx = 21;
Nt = 100;
dt = Ts/Nt;
dx = L/(Nx - 1);
\[Omega] = 0.7;
\[Theta] = 0.50;
\[Epsilon]T = 0.001;

X = Join[Range[0, L/2, L/2/IntegerPart@(4/5 Nx)], 
   2^Table[i, {i, Log[2., L/2 + dx], 
      1, (1 - Log[2., L/2 + dx])/(IntegerPart@(Nx/5) - 1)}]];
DX = Differences[X];
T0 = T[0, X];

A = ConstantArray[0, {Nx, Nx}];
A[[1, 1]] = 0.5 \[Omega] DX[[1]]; 
A[[1, 2]] = 0.5 (1. - \[Omega]) DX[[1]];
For[i = 2, i <= Nx - 1, i++,
  A[[i, i - 1]] = 0.5 (1. - \[Omega]) DX[[i]];
  A[[i, i]] = \[Omega] DX[[i]];
  A[[i, i + 1]] = 0.5 (1. - \[Omega]) DX[[i]];
  ];
A[[Nx, Nx - 1]] = 0.5 (1. - \[Omega]) DX[[-1]]; 
A[[Nx, Nx]] = 0.5 \[Omega] DX[[-1]];
A = SparseArray[A];

Kxx = kxx[T0]*ra[T0];
avgK = 0.5 Table[Kxx[[i]] + Kxx[[i + 1]], {i, Nx - 1}];

B = ConstantArray[0, {Nx, Nx}];
B[[1, 1]] = avgK[[1]]/DX[[1]]; B[[1, 2]] = -avgK[[1]]/DX[[1]];
For[i = 2, i <= Nx - 1, i++,
  B[[i, i - 1]] = -avgK[[i - 1]]/DX[[1]]; 
  B[[i, i]] = (avgK[[i - 1]] + avgK[[i]])/DX[[i]]; 
  B[[i, i + 1]] = -avgK[[i]]/DX[[i]];];
B[[Nx, Nx - 1]] = -avgK[[Nx - 1]]/DX[[-1]]; 
B[[Nx, Nx]] = avgK[[Nx - 1]]/DX[[-1]];
B = SparseArray[B];
```

Now it is enough to write `B` in the cell and hit `Shift+Enter` to get a crash or clear all the variables. Could anyone tell me if the same happens in case of your environment? My is Windows 10, Mathematica 12.

When the code is run as a WLS it does not happen.

Comment: Is every single line of your code necessary to reproduce the behiavour? If not, could you simplify it as much as possible (without changing the behaviour of course)?

Comment: @anderstood unfortunately yes, all the code causes such behavior. If I remove some parts, it does not happen.

Comment: Unix and version 11.3 here, code runs without crashing the kernel and manipulating matrix `B` does not seem to cause problems.

Comment: Works for me in version 12.0 on Windows 10 32-bit, producing B and several errors, e.g. "InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {700.} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.".

Comment: Maybe a memory issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem appears to have been a faulty computer, not Mathematica.

Comment: Just because it's only one computer demonstrating the issue doesn't mean Mathematica is guaranteed to not be at fault. Mathematica can introduce environment specific bugs (although I am not certain if that's what is happening here)

Comment: @user6014 Perhaps it should be closed because (1) it does not have code that reproduces the problem and/or (2) it requires advice from Wolfram Support? There is evidence for all three reasons (incl. John's), even if the true reason cannot be known with absolute certainty. OTOH, there is an upvoted answer, and while it might be valid to close the question, it's probably not necessary to do so. Although it has a comment-level post as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't disagree, I just think it's unfair to go out of our way to call OP's computer "faulty" at this point :)

Comment: @user6014 That's fair. While the OP suspects the OP's computer is at issue, it's not necessarily faulty.

Comment: It's a problem seen only on one specific computer involving very complicated code. As such, I don't think it of general interest. The OP may wish to contact Wolfram, but this isn't the channel.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is an environment specific bug. I have used the exact file on a different machine, which also has Win 10 and Mathematica 12 and the bug does not reproduce. It may be some problem with the exact PC.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I also have Win10 X64 and MMA12.

Kernal did not crash.

Comment: Pretty much just [what[@user64494 said](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202648/mathematica-clears-all-definitions-or-crashes-with-the-following-code-can-anyon#comment523636_202648).